# URL with / / in IIS is redirecting to thread abort exception

Tags: iis, httprequest, iis-8.5

In my current web application, I encountered a special scenario where the HTTP request is coming with space in URL i.e., something like this: `mwebapp/ /pagetest`. I configured the URL rewrite for this scenario in IIS but it did not work for me.

Has any one come across this kind of situation, if so kindly let me know how to handle such http requests.

Regards,
Janardhan.

Comment: It looks like some defect to me on caller side. If it is your component, fix it. If not then let the server behave as it because one particular segment/parameter which is expected by server is not sent by caller.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, Yes you are right the problem with the caller. But is there is any way to handle it?

Comment: I would say don't try to handle this at your end. Technically or functionally a missing parameter is error.

Comment: Just want to redirect to a custom error page, right now after configring the custom error page also IIS is not redirecting the site to custom error page, instead it shows the request has been terminated. Do you have any idea on how o redirect to custom error page.